# I.I.D. collection of discrete random varible

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X_1,\ldots,X_{100}$ is an i.i.d. collection of a discrete random variable with $$Pr(X_i=k)=\frac{e^{-2}2^k}{k!}$$

A) calculate $Pr(X_7=0|X_5=5)$
the answer I got for this is 0.1357 I was wondering if this is right because I'm still having trouble understanding on how to calculate this.

B) calculate $Pr(X_1+X_2=3)$
How would I approach this problem?

Comment: For the first, by independence it is $e^{-2}$.  You got close, but is more like $0.1353$.

Answer (score 1):

1. $$P(X_7 = 0|X_5 = 5) =P(X_7 = 0) = e^{-2}\frac{2^0}{0!} =0.1353353$$
   by independence.
2. $X_1+X_2\sim\text{Pois}(4)$. Therefore

   > $P(X_1+X_2 = 3) = e^{-4}\frac{4^3}{3!} = 0.1953668.$

Answer (score 0):

1, You are right because $X_5$ and $X_7$ are independent.

2, You have $X_1$ and $X_2$ have a Poisson distribution, so are $X_1 + X_2$, i.e. $X_1 + X_2 \sim $ Poisson (4). So, $Pr(X_1+X_2 = 3) = \frac{4^3e^{-4}}{3!}$.